# Why IE11 is working pointing to "localhost" but not "127.0.0.1"

Tags: c#, windows, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have some tests written in C# run fine on my machine pointing to "localhost" or "127.0.0.1". I sent them to my lead to verify and they fail only on IE only when pointing to "127.0.0.1". Works on chrome and firefox without any issue. See screenshots for errors. We use same version of windows and IE as well. Verified we have taken same windows pathces and updates. Checked IIS bindings and windows host file to verify we have same setitngs. Only thing is different is(may be) the switch which shouldn't matter I guess. Can't figure out what's going on. Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

we are using 
OS Name Microsoft Windows 7 Professional
Version 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
IE: 11(11.0.9600.172391S)
[image]

Comment: these pictures are tiny.. could you upload them to an album in [imgur](http://imgur.com) or something?

Comment: http://imgur.com/llt4iqt  
http://imgur.com/eQkL1zu  
http://imgur.com/BliewFL

Comment: Have you configured **both** machines with the correct protected mode settings?

Comment: @Arran Yes, Enhanced protected mode and security zone were set same. Made sure

Comment: anyone? we still encountered this issue